# Validate if more than one item was selected using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code allows the user to select one or more models of cars graphically on a web page.  I am in need to check if more than one was selected. How can I get this to count the number of selected items and if it's great than one alert("something")?? In short, I need to know if both Lexus and Inifiti were chosen in the example code here. I really need the count so if it's greater than 1 selected. Any help is great appreciated, not sure what I am doing wrong .

```
  <div class="options-item-wrapper clearfix">
    <?php
    $modelOptions = array(
        0 => array('title' => 'Lexus'),
        1 => array('title' => 'Infiniti')
    );

    foreach ($modelOptions as $modelOption) {
        $selected = '';
          $optionValue = '';

        if(in_array($modelOption['title'], $modelArray)) {
            $selected = 'selected';
            $optionValue = '<input class="vehicle-option"  
            type="hidden" name="model[]"       
            value="'.$modelOption['title'].'">';
        }

        echo '<div class="options-item '.$selected.'" data-vehicle="'.
        $modelOption['title'].'">
        <div>'.$modelOption['title'].'</div>
        '.$optionValue.'    </div>';
    }
    ?>
  </div>
```

I have tried this but no luck thus far :

```
    var checkedNum = $('input[name="model[]"]:selected').length;
    alert(checkedNum);
    if (checkedNum > 1) {
        alert('Validating the form2');
        // User didn't check any checkboxes
    } else {
        die();
    }
```

Comment: You should post the resulted HTML instead of the PHP.

Comment: may your working fiddle will help us.

Comment: @Mike Q maybe this will help? https://jsfiddle.net/6Loyke7b/1 Anyway, I think if you are using checkboxes you need `:checked` instead of `:selected`. I believe the latter is for dropdowns.

Comment: `:selected` only really works for `<option>` elements...

Comment: maybe use checked instead if you're using some kind of input

Comment: `:checked` only works for checkboxes and radio buttons... which I don't believe OP is using

Comment: @HanletEscaño  , you should have posted yours as the answer, it was correct !!!! thank you!  Technically you were first...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because hidden input elements don't have a selected state.

If I understand your code correctly, you add the class 'selected' to your options items if they're selected. Wouldn't you just need to count the number of options items with the selected class?

```
var checkedNum = $('.options-item.selected').length;
alert(checkedNum);
if (checkedNum > 1) {
    alert('Validating the form2');
    // User didn't check any checkboxes
} else {
    die();
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly ... I can now tell the user to only select ONE item if they are going to use a keyword search. Thank you